# Iterative QuickSort with O(log n) extra space (stack)

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

Hello I have written QuickSort with stack but I'm not sure this alghoritm is using O(n) extra space or O(log n) extra space which I want to make.

I will be very thankful if somebody could look at this code and tell me what extra space uses here stack and if it uses O(n) extra space how to do it to use only O(log n) extra space?

Here is my code

```
public class QuickSortStack{

public static void quickSortStack(int[] tab, int L, int R) {

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack();


    while (L < R || !stack.isEmpty()) {

        if (L < R) {
            int q = lomutoPartition(tab, L, R);

            stack.push(R);
            R = q - 1;

        } else {

            L = R + 2;
            R = stack.pop();

        }
    }//end of while
}//end of QS method

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] test= {-4,2,-4,2,-12,5,-1,6,-9,0,9}; 

    Random random = new Random();
    int[] tab= new int[20];


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tab[i] = random.nextInt(50);
        System.out.print(tab[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    quickSortStos(tab, 0, tab.length - 1);

    for (int x : tab
            ) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }

}
public static void swap(int[] tab, int i, int j) {

    int tmp = tab[i];
    tab[i] = tab[j];
    tab[j] = tmp;

}

public static int lomutoPartition(int[] tab, int L, int R){

    int i = L-1;
    int x = tab[R]; 


    for(int j = L; j < R; j++){

        if(tab[j] <= x){

            i = i+1;
            swap(tab, i, j);

        }

    }

    swap(tab, i+1, R);
    return i+1;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to guarantee O(log N) space usage, you need to push the larger of the two partitions and loop with the smaller one. That's equivalent to a recursive solution where the non-tail recursion is always the smaller partition, guaranteeing a stack depth of no more than log<sub>2</sub>N.

When you do that, you will need to push both boundaries of the partition, or at least a boolean which tells you whether it was the first or second partition.

Fwiw, the common experience is that the iterative solution is not faster than a recursive solution. The recursive implementation is safe as long as you tail-call optimize the second recursion (for the larger partition); if your language doesn't guarantee TCO, it's easy to do it by hand.

Comment: Ok I get it. Thanks for help.